# SQL default constraint not working on foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I added a default constraint on an existing foreign key column but its not working.

I tried adding a Default Constraint on a foreign key column but its defaulting to different value. The column is set as a `not null Int`.

```
ALTER TABLE [A] ADD  CONSTRAINT [default_value]  DEFAULT ((3)) FOR [ForeignKeyColumn]
GO
```

I tried defaulting to 3 but its defaulting to 0.

Comment: Hmmmm....there is something wrong in your code. The constraint you posted is fine. What does your insert statement look like?

Comment: I can't replicate this: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b30a3dcbff71e2a230f3dbcd1ee82a29).

Comment: @SeanLange I am inserting it as an empty string. If i don' t provide anything i am getting error "There are more columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement."

Comment: @HarmonicaBlower sounds like you're not including a list of columns to `INSERT` the data into. Check my link above; notice I don't include `fID` in the last `INSERT`. I'm guessing you're not declaring your columns. Also, `''`<> `NULL`. They are actually very different values.

Comment: @Larnu its working when i do like you are doing. I am not sure how this will work with a entity framework request or a ETL data load.

Comment: Well there you go. When you insert an empty string it will be cast to an int. And an empty string is 0. If you want to use the default then don't insert anything for that column. Or use "default".

Answer (score 0):

From your comment:

> I am inserting it as an empty string.

Well, if you are doing:

```
insert into a (ForeignKeyColumn)
    values ('');
```

And `ForeignKeyColumn` is a number, then SQL will convert the `''` to a number.  Voila, that number is `0` -- so no default value is necessary.

Leave the `ForeignKeyColumn` out of the `insert` if you want a default value.  Or use `default`:

```
insert into a (ForeignKeyColumn)
    values (default);
```

Comment: If i do that it will work but how will it work if the request is coming from Enityframework or ETL data load with empty values but key is present?

Comment: Well trigger side do you get zeros and empty?